Solved: How to handle empty input strings? ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
score = int(input("Anzahl Schläge auf Bahn " + str(bahn + 1) + ": "))
if score <= 0:
    score = 7
elif score >= 7:
    score = 7
elif score == '':
    score = 7
scores.append(score)

I know there is a solution where I need to convert the empty str into an float. But I can't figure it out. What the script is supposed to do is set a value of 7 if the user-input is empty. (By now, if the user-input is empty my script crashes.)
I tried converting the str into a float befor turning it into an int. But I'm new to python and this confuses me. How do other programs handle empty input?
The working solution was indeed an exception handler.
#Punkte pro Bahn
while bahn < bahnen:
    print()
    scoreCheck = int(0)
    while scoreCheck <= 0:
        try:
            scoreCheck = int(input("Anzahl Schläge auf Bahn " + str(bahn + 1) + ": "))
        except ValueError:
            print("gib bitte eine ZAHL > 0 ein"), print()
    
        else:
            if scoreCheck <= 0:
                print("gib bitte eine ZAHL > 0 ein"), print()
            elif scoreCheck > MaxSchleg:
                score = MaxSchleg +1
            else:
                score = int(scoreCheck)
    bahn += 1

This works as intended. It accepts only positive integers as input.
Thanks y'all! (o.o)/

Another way: score = int(input(...) or 7) (note: the or 7 is inside the int(...) otherwise it would still be an error)

I moved the str() after checking if the input value is empty:
score = input("Anzahl Schläge auf Bahn " + str(bahn + 1) + ": ") 
if score == '':
    score = 7
else:
    score = int(score)
    if score <= 0:
        score = 7
    else:
        if score >= 7:
            score = 7


Op want the empty str into an float. I tried converting the str into a float before turning it into an int.

Why is if score >= 7 indented so much?

In current Python, you can do a chain like so: if not (0<= score <=7) which some may consider simpler to understand.

score = input("Anzahl Schläge auf Bahn " + str(bahn + 1) + ": ")

If your score is empty it will automatically go to the else block.
if score:
  score = int(score)
else:
  print("please enter an integer")


Op want the empty str into an float. I tried converting the str into a float before turning it into an int.
